# Aggregate row sum two columns on table from same key

Tags: mysql

I have a table named inward_outward where I want to group by name and show total entries, total inward count and total outward count.

This is what I have so far

```
include('includes/dbcon.php');

    $query=mysqli_query
    ($con," SELECT name from inward_outward,
    ( SELECT  count(status) from inward_outward WHERE status ='inward' )As count_1,
    ( SELECT count(status) from inward_outward WHERE status ='out' )As count_2,
    ( SELECT count(status) from inward_outward WHERE 1 )As count_3
    GROUP BY name")

    or die(mysqli_error($con));
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){


    echo "<tr>";    
echo "<td>" . $row['inspector_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['count_1'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['count_2'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['count_3'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
      }
```

I want to take count from status column where status = 'inward' and status = 'out' then group by name

Comment: I have moved your comment into the body post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on what you want, but I think this will come closer:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(status = 'inward') AS in_ct,
       SUM(status = 'out')    AS out_ct,
       COUNT(*)               AS both
    FROM inward_outward
    GROUP BY name;
```

Notes:

- `SUM(boolean-expr)` counts the number of TRUEs
- `COUNT(*)` counts rows; `COUNT(x)` counts the number of non-null `x`
- `GROUP BY` should list all the non-aggregates, and nothing else.
- Subqueries are not needed *in this case*.
- `FROM` must come *after* the items selected.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is the correct . It worked fine.